# Graded $C^*$ algebra homomorphism

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, graded-algebras

I am pretty sure I have some definition wrong. But I do not see where. Here is the context:

---

Consider the $C^*$ algebra of continuously compactly supported functions $\Bbb R$ into $\Bbb C$.

$$C_0(\Bbb R)$$
Then there is a grading giving by even and odd functions.

It is claimed that the map $f \mapsto f(0)$, 
$$ C_0(\Bbb R) \rightarrow \Bbb C$$

Is a graded $*$-homomoprhism.

---

This does not make sense to me, if $f$ is even function, there is no restriction on $f(0)$. In particular, it would not be a **graded** morphism to the grading on $\Bbb C = \Bbb R \oplus i \Bbb R$?

Comment: Not important, but the notation $C_0(\mathbb R)$ usually denotes continuous functions $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb C$ vanishing at infinity.  The standard notation for continuous compactly supported functions is $C_c(\mathbb R)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grading on $\mathbb C$ is given by the decomposition $(\mathbb C)^+=\mathbb C$ and $(\mathbb C)^-=\{0\}$.  With this grading, the map $f\mapsto f(0)$ is a graded $*$-homomorphism.

Comment: Thanks  a lot, if you have time hope you do not mind looking at my new posts, I am quite lost with some definitions of $C^*$ algebras.